# Мне нужно получать время сервера из Firestore , но я получаю null

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase, firestore

Я релизую приложение на kotlin , где есть возможность общаться в чате , но я не могу использовать `Date()` или `Calendar`, потому что я получаю локальное время с устройства , тогда я пытаюсь использовать следующий код.

```
data class Message(
var message:String,
var id:String,
var receiverID:String=" ",
@ServerTimestamp
var date: Date? = null,
var isChecked:Boolean,
var type:String,)
```

Это работает если я просто захожу в чат тогда мои сообщения сортируются по времени правильно , но при отправке сообщения у меня срабатывает слушатель и следующая строка мне возвращает null

```
var date = doc.getTimestamp(KEY_MESSAGE_DATE)
```

Это слушатель сообщений

```
database
        .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
        .document(preferenceManager.getString(KEY_USER_ID)!!)
        .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
        .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            if (error != null) {
                return@addSnapshotListener
            } else {
                if (value == null) {
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                } else {

                    for (documentChange in value.documentChanges) {
                        if (documentChange.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                            var doc = documentChange.document
                            if (doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID) == receiverUser.uid) {
                                var text = doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE).toString()
                                var id = doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE_ID).toString()
                                var receiverId =
                                    doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID).toString()
                                var date = doc.getTimestamp(KEY_MESSAGE_DATE)
                                var isChecked = doc.getBoolean(KEY_MESSAGE_ISCHECKED)!!
                                var type = doc.getString(KEY_TYPE_MESSAGE).toString()
                                var message =
                                    Message(text, id, receiverId, date!!.toDate(), isChecked, type)
                                if (message !in messages) {
                                    messages.add(message)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    messages.sortBy { it -> it.date }
                    var messages_test = ArrayList(messages)
                    userChatAdpater.updateList(messages_test)
                    if (messages.size != 0) {
                        mBinding.rvUserChat.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size - 1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

так как метка еще не успевает сгенерироваться , это приводит к тому что я не могу сразу же отобразить сообщение , мне нужно перезаходить на экран чата , есть ли способы решить данную проблему?

Пример того что я получаю с сервера

```
date -> {Value@24504} "# com.google.firestore.v1.Value@891ec4c9
 map_value {
 fields {
key: "type"
value {
  string_value: "server_timestamp"
  }
}
fields {
  key: "local_write_time"
  value {
    timestamp_value {
      nanos: 507000000
      seconds: 1661004559
    }
  }
}
}"
```

Comment: Добавьте больше подробностей в вопрос, сложно сказать имея только модель и какую-то строку без контекста

Comment: Добавил код слушатея сообщений

Comment: есть пример того что с сервера вы получаете и не можете обработать?

Comment: получаю null , но только при отправке сообщения , возможно это из-за того что у меня по умолчанию в моделе Message date присваивается null , но я пытался без этого ничеге не получалось , сейчас я попробовал использовать timeApi и парсить json , но все равно при отправке проблема с датами опять с одного устройства 20 августа , а со второго 21августа приходит , и не понимаю почему

Comment: возможно это связано с тем что на телефоне у меня стоит 12-ти часовой формат времени , но это же не должно влиять если время я получаю с timeApi через json

Comment: Я понял свою ошибку , для того чтоб достать дату при генерации при помощи @SreverTimeStamp я использовал getDate ,  но в ответ от сервера получаю map

Comment: сделайте просто ещё одну модель на это поле и все

Comment: я попытался получить просто объект без выдления типа , но все равно получил null , хотя если смотреть через дебаггер то ответ такой же как я прикрепил в вопросе

Comment: попробуйте поменять название поля чтобы оно соответствовало названию из ответа сервера, потому что вы пытаетесь десериализовать то чего нет

Comment: Насколько я понял сервер сначала добавляет записи в базу и сразу присылает колбек на это событие, потом рассчитывает время (видимо асинхронно), записывает его в базу и должен ещё раз прилететь колбек уже с датой. У вас наверное второй вызов отсеивается на проверке `if (documentChange.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED)`. Нужна ли эта проверка вообще? Если сообщение удалено или, как в данном случае, изменено - на экране это не отобразится

Comment: вызов проходит , я решил проблему благодаря SNTPClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такую модель можно попробовать:

```
data class DateModel(
    val nanos: Long,
    val seconds: Long
)

data class Message(
    var message: String,
    var id: String,
    var receiverID: String = " ",
    @SerializedName("timestamp_value")
    var timeStamp: DateModel? = null,
    var isChecked: Boolean,
    var type: String,
)
```

ваша модель ищет поле которого нет в вашем json, либо я чего-то не понимаю и data смаппится на timestamp_value

Comment: Ответ сервера прикрепленный к вопросу это результат получения   поля date , но я его получаю это видно через дебаггер , но в значение переменной куда я записываю ответ присваивается все равно null , сейчас я попробую ваше решение

Comment: К сожалению не помогло так как , я получаю null только при отправке сообщения , когда сообщение нужно отобразить сразу , в случае же когда я просто захожу в чат то у меня появляются все сообщения правильно ,  в том числе те сообщения при отправке которых я получаю null , я полностью не понимаю что делать в такой ситуации  , и как мне добавлять время в отправку сообщения независимо от устройства  с которого оно отправляется

Comment: У вас же в вопросе не null, обработка значит неправильно сделана. Если сразу после отправки сообщения у вас с сервера приходит  null, то подставляйте время устройства в секундах, в противном случае проверьте как вы обрабатываете ответ сервера после отправки

Comment: Либо апи firebase предоставляет все из коробки

Comment: я создал новый вопрос где все подробно расписал и показал , если вам не сложно могли бы вы его посмотреть? я был бы вам очень благодарен